# Universal Windows App: Is it possible to make a borderless transparent window?

Tags: win-universal-app

Is it possible to make a transparent window with no title bar for a Universal Windows Application?

Comment: Not currently. That would allow an app to steal passwords by covering, say, your banking app.

Comment: What are you trying to build where you'd want that?